# Is there a way to backtest Heikin Ashi strategy and get appropriate result? instead of wrong open and close price

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading

I am developing a scalping strategy using heikin ashi, in the backtesting, the winning rate and equity growth is incredibly high, but I know it's unreal, because all the postion entry and exit price are based on heikin ashi prices which much different from the real open and close price in my favor.

I tried to use request.security to get real close price, and using limit order to open and exit at real price level. however the real price always higher than Heikin Ashi close prices, that makes the position still open at Heikin Ashi prices.

Is there a way to force the backtest open position in a certain price? so that I can get to know how the strategy performs live.

```
    s=request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1", close)
    ......
    strategy.entry("BarUp", strategy.long, limit= s[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

When backtesting heikinashi, you should always use the standard candlestick chart and request data from the heikin ashi bars.

So, your strategy needs to run on the standard candlestick chart and calculate your conditions with the heikinashi values. This way, it would be using real price values.